# external website storage

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, bandwidth, cloud-hosting

One of my clients is a business consultant, and stores powerpoint presentations on her website for conference attendees to download after a conference.

There are 91 files totalling 111MB.

I want to host these outside of my own web hosting account, to save disk space and bandwidth.

Any recommendations on (hopefully free) providers?

I just signed up for a free web hosting account with host-ed, and they required a domain be attached to the account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox.com gives you 2Gb free. You can make some of it available to other people.

Comment: This is what I use too. Put files you want to share in your [Public folder](http://www.dropbox.com/help/16), and they each get a URL that you can pass on or link to.

Answer (score 2):

Those are rather large for PowerPoint. Also be sure in PowerPoint to double click any image and hit compress and uncheck "Apply only to this picture". The file size should drop dramatically.

After compression you could use:

Google Docs (1GB)
Dropbox (2GB)
Windows Skydrive (25GB) but with 50MB max file size

Comment: He needs 111Mb, not 10Gb. However, good tip on compressing images.

Comment: Oh I misread as 91 files each totaling 111MB. D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

Host them in a FTP Server with anonymous access. A File Sharing service or in a free hosting service.

### If you choose the FTP Server

The ftp service and the files can be placed in the computer of your client which -with internet connection and the appropriate NAT configuration- will allow users to gain access to the files, no matters of its size.

For information on FTP Services take a look at this: https://superuser.com/questions/296669/how-to-set-up-a-ftp-server-for-multiple-users-with-their-separate-directories/296673#296673 my suggestion and other people's suggestion may be useful for this case.

### The File Sharing Service

will force you to maintain dynamic links, unless you have a paid account in RapidShare, Megapload, etc. However, this isn't a kind of a "PRO" solution but it is yet valid.

### There are free hosting services

With unlimited monthly file transfer, and unlimited hosting size, but limited file size upload (like the http://x10hosting.com, make sure you read the rules, when I tried to upload a 4 GB File they said: "no-oh! you can't!" LOL!)

There are other alternatives that I use for those cases, which includes the creation of an HTTP service, with direct http access to the files, which allow you  to give a certain format to the files that you wish to share in public, take a look at: http://geppettvs.servehttp.com/resources.html, http://geppettvs.servehttp.com/documents.html,
and
http://geppettvs.servehttp.com/downloads.html)

[image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out http://www.slideshare.net/ in addition to hosting presentations with the option to embed them in your site they have apps built-in to share on common social media sites (your client can add a presentations tab to their facebook account or embed them on Linkedin). They have free and paid options.